# Symplectic nonequivalent subspaces of a given dimension in a symplectic space

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let us be given a symplectic space of dimension $2n$ $(V, w)$. Symplectic equivalent subspaces $L_1, L_2$ are such subspaces $V$ for which there exists a symplectic operator $A$ such that $L_1=AL_2$. The question is as follows: how many symplectic nonequivalent subspaces of a given dimension $l$ exist.
I know that two arbitrary symplectic subspaces are symplectic equivalent if the constraints of the original symplectic form on them have the same rank. I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962167/is-the-symplectic-complement-of-a-symplectic-subspace-is-still-symplectic-in-inf) about what the rank of a symplectic form is, but it did not become clearer how to count the number of such subspaces.